# fill points on the multi-line chart with the same color as lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

On the bar-line chart points on the lines are blue ([working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/udfz4Lwx/8/)), although there is a function to fill the points with the color of the line

```
// circle points | кружочки на лініях

    point.selectAll("circle") 
    .data(function(d){ return d.values; })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.date) + x.rangeBand()/2;
      })
     .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d.value); })
     .attr("r", 3)
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because d.name is different in both cases. d.name doesnt exit on line 132 where you are trying to fill the circle. So its just getting the first colour from the colour scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### debugging

To debug a problem like this, use `console.log` function inside the function setting the `fill` attribute:

```
style("fill", function(d) { 
    console.log('d is', d)
    return color(d.name);
});
```

You'll see that there is no `d.name`. This attribute is not passed to `point`:

```
// circle points | кружочки на лініях

    point.selectAll("circle") 
    .data(function(d){ return d.values; }) // point has access to d.values, not to d.name.
```

#### solution

To fix the problem you may do the following:

Add the `name` property inside each item of values array

```
point.selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d) {

    // add name inside each value inside `d.values`
    d.values.forEach(function(value) {
      value.name = d.name
    })

    return d.values;
  })
```

Then your `fill` function will work correctly.

[Fixed example](https://jsfiddle.net/udfz4Lwx/9/) to illustrate the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As per initial answer, you had different data associated with circles, which was `d.value` not `d.name`.
Also you were missing a hash sign in your colour range declaration:
`var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["c9bebe", "#787676", "#4d4dff"]);`, which should obviously stand as:
`var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#c9bebe", "#787676", "#4d4dff"]);`.

One more thing I could add to all this discussion is that you can, for simplicity and clarity, associate your colours with groups containing `circles` directly. So instead of adding styles to `circle` elements, you can add it to the group:

```
var point = column.append("g")
  .attr({
    "class": "line-point",
    "fill": function(d) { return color(d.name); }
    });
```

And `console.log` at different points of your code is a great way of finding issue, in a methodic way.

[JSFiddle adjusted](https://jsfiddle.net/udfz4Lwx/11/)